# Username and Password not being entered for Authentication popup using ntlm plugin

Tags: cypress, ntlm

I have installed and configured the cypress-ntlm-auth plugin in order to enter the Username and Password for a Sign In popup on a test site.
I was initially getting the 401 Unauthorised Error but no longer get this Error and the Sign In popup is is visible when running npx cypress-ntlm open and then running test in Cypress UI.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you try opening this in your normal browser and check whether this is bypassing the auth pop-up - `https://username:password@yourwebsite.net` ?

Comment: @AlapanDas thank you this has bypassed the Windows Auth pop-up

Answer (score 0):

In your test You can directly use this, without any plugin:

```js
cy.visit('https://username:password@yourwebsite.net')
```

Or, if you want to use env variable for username and password you can do:

```js
cy.visit('https://' + Cypress.env('username') + ':' + Cypress.env('password') + '@yourwebsite.net')
```